# How to resize bitmap decoded from URL?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

I am using bitmap to get a image from a url using this

```
public void loadImage(String url){
try {

       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Is there anyway i can resize the image from here? setting the width and the height of it still keeping the resolution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use: `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this too.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1; // 1 = 100% if you write 4 means 1/4 = 25% 
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(),
                                                                   null, bmOptions);
bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: don't you need to pass options anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Picasso(very simple!):

Picasso.with(context) .load(url) .resize(10, 10) .into(imageView)

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: This worked great for me! was using volley..the whole thing was painful when dealing with images

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set the width and height property of imageView in XML?

I find out that the image from url is resized automatically so that it can fit in that imageView.